# I created a textarea box and i want to validate multiple emails in it

Tags: php

I created a textarea box and i want to validate multiple emails in it. I tried validating them through a seperator "comma" but failed when we enter only one email id. Need a better solution in PHP

Comment: What is the question, what have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 1):

Try using explode to construct your array, in this sort of way:

```
$addresses = explode(',', $addresses);
foreach ($addresses as $address){
    $address = trim($address); // trim removes excess surrounding whitespace
    validate_email($address); // your function here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stab-in-the dark... use `explode()` on the string based on the comma, and then loop round it...

Answer (score 0):

Avoid PHP4 shenigans and make fair use of your tools - use multiple inputs, and wrap them in a array:

```
<input name="mails[]" type="email required="false"/>
<input name="mails[]" type="email required="false"/>
<input name="mails[]" type="email required="false"/>
<input name="mails[]" type="email required="false"/>
```

In your PHP script you may access them inside `$_REQUEST['mails]` - it will be an array you can loop over.

If you want to add a new email field, it's just a line of jQuery in case.